# permanent USB port names? (Linux)

Tags: linux, serial-port, port

I have two Arduinos now used by my program.
SInce I'm on Linux and new to Linux, the port isn't static, like "com3" and "com6", I think it's "ttyUSB0" for the first Arduino which is connected, and "ttyUSB1" for the second and so on. But since both are connected when the OS boots, can I be certain that the port names will remain the same? Or is there some other way to access ports by name?

Answer (score 3):

use udev!

```
udevadm info -a -n /dev/ttyUSB1 | grep '{serial}' | head -n1
```

should give you the USB interfaces serial number.

then you can write udev rules:

example

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001", ATTRS{serial}=="A6008isP", SYMLINK+="arduino"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001", ATTRS{serial}=="A7004IXj", SYMLINK+="buspirate"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001", ATTRS{serial}=="FTDIF46B", SYMLINK+="cisco.serial"
```

Comment: The "ATTRS{serial}" is the serial nubmer?

Comment: That's a parameter for the serial number of the USB device.

Comment: A bit confusing, which is the serial number/string I can input in my program?

Comment: you use the first command to figure that out.

Comment: I got this: `ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:14.0"` So its `0000:00:14.0`? I just dont understand what you mean by "then you can write udev rule"

Comment: It does appear to be.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90261/discussion-between-matt-joyce-and-leo-ervin).

Comment: I tried that command on every port and Arduino . THey all give 0000:00:14.0

Comment: Did you find any solution for the problem with `    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:14.0"`?