# PySerial "better" port names for Linux?

Tags: linux, serial-port, pyserial

Followup question to this: [permanent USB port names? (Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32702885/permanent-usb-port-names-linux)

On Windows the port names don't change between actual physical ports. They are along the lines of "COM3", "COM6", etc.
On Linux, if I plug one USB device first , it will be "ttyUSB0" and if I plug the same device second in any other physical port it will be "ttyUSB1". That won't work if I want to, say, have 2 Arduinos connected via Pyserial to the PC.

In the above answer I was shown a way to get an IP-like "serial name". How can I feed that to the PySerial class instead?

Answer (score 0):

An example:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial(port = "/dev/USBNAME", baudrate=9600)
ser.close()
ser.open()
if ser.isOpen(): 
     ser.write("test")
```

Comment: I dont seem to be able to use the serial number we got as USBNAME, only ttyUSB* seems to work..

Comment: did you make the udev changes in /etc/udev ( or /etc/dev.d/ ) ?

Comment: Changes? I must have not understood some part.